# Delete datagrid column programmatically

Tags: wpf, datagrid, columnheader

I have datagrid in wpf. When I do mouse-over on column header, There is one close button will appear.

I want to have some functionality so when I click on that button, whole column should be deleted.

I have wrote this.

```
      <DataTemplate x:Key="AdornerDataTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Button Content="X" Width="26" Height="26" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ctrls:RhinoDataGrid}}, Path=RemoveColumnCommand}" Background="{DynamicResource GridHeaderMouseOverBrush}"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

I can see that RemoveColumnCommand is executed but it doesn't have index of column. How would I know on which column I clicked.

[image: screenshot]

Pls help me.

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass the column as `CommandParameter` via a binding. The index itself should not be needed.